# Get number of constraints associated with a column

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I have been trying to get the number of constraints associated with a column using SQL command.

I would like to know if there exists something like

```
column.number_of_constraints
```

How can I get this information?

I'm working with an `Oracle` database.

Comment: You usually check the data dictionary of your RDBMS. To help you out here, we need to know what RDBMS you are using.

Comment: This is probably a better question for http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is unclear why you are wanting to do this, but does something like `show create table tablename`; help?

Comment: @kojow7 didn't work.

Comment: @Baronz Thank you, didn't know about that site.

Comment: Don't forget to tag your RBDMs either here or there. It is a very important information as each RDBMs has your own defined data dictionary as @Olli mentioned.

Comment: @Tiasn What happened when you tried? Did you replace *tablename* with the name of your table?

Comment: @JorgeCampos Sorry for that, it is Oracle database.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in regard to Oracle database. Thanks

`ALL_CONS_COLUMNS` describes columns that are accessible to the current user and that are specified in constraints.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_1042.htm

You need to query the **data dictionary** to see the table columns and the corresponding constraints.
You can try below query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM user_cons_columns
 WHERE table_name = '<your table name>';
```

Comment: How do you know it is oracle?

Comment: @JorgeCampos since the question didn't specify, what's wrong with providing an answer that might help?

Comment: @DaveCosta Thank you!, it is Oracle.

Comment: @DaveCosta  It turns out that it is oracle and point taken. I will not make this mistake again :)